# JavaFX referencing an array list of a smaller size to a master array list

Tags: arrays, arraylist, javafx

I am working on a mock hotel reservation system and I am having trouble correctly referencing my array lists. Each room object that is created is stored in the master array list roomArray and stored in an array list called availableRooms.

availableRooms is declared as

```
    ArrayList<Room> availableRooms = roomArray;
```

Once a room is created, its number and availability is posted to a list view in the employee menu and a list view in the guest menu. Once the room is booked, the room is removed from the list view in the guest menu and availableRooms and the availability of that room changes to [booked] in the employee menu list view. Everything works fine until I start trying different input sequences like creating and booking rooms between both menus. How can I keep track of the indices of the selected rooms in the list views so that each element of availableRooms is a reference to the correct room object in roomArray? roomArray is private and availableRooms is public, they are both in the same class roomManagement.

Nathan

Comment: JavaFX has a [FilteredList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/transformation/FilteredList.html) construct.  That might be a more appropriate type to use for your availableRooms array (so your question may become an [x y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).  It would also likely remove your any need for the cause of your indexing issue.  To use it, you would add a BooleanProperty to Room and filter your list based upon that.  The filtered list can be used directly as the item list backing to an availableRoomsListView.

Comment: Note: if you set `availableRooms = roomArray` as you have in your question, then availableRooms *is* the roomArray, so modifying availableRooms also changes the roomArray and vice versa.  From the rest of your description, that would not seem to be what you wanted to achieve.  You might get a better answer with an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).