# JavaFX reference a master array list

Tags: java, arrays, listview, arraylist, javafx

I am writing a mock hotel reservation system with two menus, employee and guest. Created rooms are stored in a master array called roomArray and added to a list view in the employee menu, and added to a list view in the guest menu. Rooms can be available or booked, however only available rooms are shown in the guest menu list view, so I might have 5 rooms but only 2 show in the guest menu list view. If the user clicks on the second one, I don't want to try and book the index 1 room in the main roomArray static ArrayList because they don’t match up.

For example, say in the employee list view I have three rooms, two of which are booked. In the guest list view, only the available rooms show up. So the list view on the right would show a selected index of 0, but the same index in the master roomArray is 1 for that same room. How can I make an intermediary of array list of available rooms that reference rooms in the master list?

Nathan

Comment: Another thing you can do is use a HashMap. The Key can be the unique room number and the mapped value can be booked or notbooked.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43598587/javafx-referencing-an-array-list-of-a-smaller-size-to-a-master-array-list?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using JavaFX, you should use `ObservableList` for your rooms. Additionally, you would need to use [`FilteredList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/transformation/FilteredList.html) and [`FXCollections.observableArrayList(extractor)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList-javafx.util.Callback-).

This is how you can implement it:

```
public class Room {
    public enum State {AVAILABLE, BOOKED}

    private final ObjectProperty<State> state = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(AVAILABLE);
    public final ObjectProperty<State> stateProperty() { return state; }
    public final State getState() { return state.get(); }
    public final void setState(final State value) { state.set(state); }
}
```

Main class:

```
private final ObservableList<Room> rooms;
public final ObservableList<Room> getRooms() { return rooms; }

private final ObservableList<Room> guestRooms;
public final ObservableList<Room> getGuestRooms() { return guestRooms; }

// Constructor
public MyClass() {
    rooms = FXCollections.observableArrayList(room -> new Observable[] {room.stateProperty()});

    guestRooms = rooms.filtered(room -> room.getState() == Room.State.AVAILABLE);
}
```

The `guestRooms` list is just a wrapper for `rooms` list, filtered with a `Predicate`. The filtered list will change according to the `rooms` list, but it will only react to changes to the list itself (add, remove, replace of elements). To make sure it responds to changes of the state of existing rooms, you need to use `FXCollections.observableArrayList(extractor)` overload. This overload allows you to control which property in each `Room` object would also trigger a `ListChangeListener.Change`, which would also causes the filtered list to update itself.